# "hash sum mismatch" error when doing update

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, hash

I have just installed 16.04 LTS. However, I cannot update.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Fetched 34,3 MB in 1h 51min 52s (5.110 B/s)                                     
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/e145fc3961ba6091b075afe8b3a89a5f58e1346b7d6cb0a1f4166dfcc3201392  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to many thing, but didn't help.
I tried the solutions from [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error), but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @GautamVashisht  No I tried that solutions but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt clean` after doing `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` ?

Comment: It helped thanks, but now, I cannot install anything from terminal. For example:`sudo apt-get install opera
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package opera is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'opera' has no installation candidate
`

Comment: Do `sudo apt update` first and then do `sudo apt install opera`

Comment: @GautamVashisht I am sorry to forget to say, yes I did update than install opera.

Comment: Opera is not present in official Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. To install it, take a look at this link :- http://askubuntu.com/questions/765483/how-can-i-install-the-opera-browser-from-the-terminal

Comment: @GautamVashisht thanks for your help! it solved my problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get rid of this error, hit the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal window.

Then type the commands given below in the terminal one-by-one:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```

Comment: If you know the invalid file, you can just remove it, and update will run faster. Otherwise, you will have to download all again.

Comment: I've used your solution, but it still failed with the following error messages:  W: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz  Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: @Clock ZHONG    Run `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*` in terminal. If it still doesn't work, take a look at this link - https://askubuntu.com/questions/679233/failed-to-fetch-hash-sum-mismatch-tried-rm-apt-list-but-didnt-work . Hope it helps !

Comment: @ Gautam Vashisht , thanks! I've fixed this issue by changing the repository server to the US UBUNTU official site. It seems not all Ubuntu's repository servers maintained well. I'm not sure how Ubuntu maintains those free repository servers, but it's obvious  that there are some problems in the current management solution.

Comment: Actually, why is this solution ignoring the security warning that this error message describes? why is it secure to just ignore this warning saying that the update source is maliciously modified or insecure?