# Unable to update Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 Hash Sum mismatch error

Tags: updates, 17.10

I tried going to the the links mentioned below. I tried changing the servers.
Still i am getting the Hash Sum MisMatch Error. I tried updating using the terminal and using the software updater.

How do i proceed to  update?

["hash sum mismatch" error when doing update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846767/hash-sum-mismatch-error-when-doing-update)

[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Failed to fetch / Hash Sum mismatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918274/ubuntu-16-04-lts-failed-to-fetch-hash-sum-mismatch)

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/779924/341706 You just need to update with a different compression method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected to another wifi network, this solved my problem.

Comment: or another Ubuntu server as per Settings -> Software & Updates -> download from (pick new location here)   ... for me this solved it